# Change swift UILabel when change elements in array

Tags: arrays, swift, uilabel

I have this problem that I am unable to resolve:
I have 2 file one with the array of elements (names and images) and the other file where I try to call array elements to change the text in the UILable.

the code of the array in the second file:

```
var items: [ItemInfo] = [("AAZ-2", "AAZ-02"), ("BACT01", "Anti-Bacterial"), ("FK01", "Fresh Keeping"), ("mouse", "Anti-Rodents"), ("RIC01", "Anti-VOC"), ("UV01", "UV Protection")]
```

In the other file to get access to the variable and the array from the other file I created this:

```
let demoViewController: DemoViewController = DemoViewController()
```

Now I create a function where I get the code to call the file from the array

```
func newLable(){
     if demoViewController.items.enumerated().first(where: {$0.element.title == "AAZ-02"}) != nil{
           textLabel.text = "text1"

    }else if demoViewController.items.enumerated().first(where: {$0.element.title == "Anti-Bacterial"}) != nil{
               textLabel.text = "tex2"

    }
```

But every time try to run the app when I switch element between the first (element of the array) and the second I receive the same text in the label (the output is: text1 as in the code).

Thanks everyone for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a misunderstanding of what "first" means.

First does not mean *find the item at the first index*, but it means it *finds the first item (at any index) that fits your search*.

So when you ask your array for the "first" item, that satisfies your predicate (e.g. equal to "AAZ-02") then it will always find an answer no matter where exactly that item is. So when you switch the first two items, this function will find the item, although it is on a higher index. And that means, that your "else" - path will never be executed.

You better try this:

```
// Pass in your itemInfo you want to search for 
func newLabel(forItem item : ItemInfo) {

     // search the first occurrence of your item
     if demoViewController.items.enumerated().first(where: {$0.element.title == item.title}) != nil {

         // if found -> set the itemInfo as the labelTitle
         textLabel.text = item.title
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, at this point I had arrived there too, any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: edited my answer and tried to correct your code, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but does not read "ItemInfo" maybe there is a problem in reading it [link](https://imgur.com/a/OY0tE1x)

Comment: You yourself have this line of code posted: var items: [ItemInfo] = [("AAZ-2", "AAZ-02"), ("BACT01", ... so I assumed you have a Type called ItemInfo. Cant help you anymore, if you don't create a small but complete project that simulates your problem.

Comment: I find the solution thanks, just add `DemoViewController.ItemInfo` thanks again